# How do you distinguish between NULL and an empty string in GetSchema("Columns") COLUMN_DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, database-schema, mysql.data

I am writing some code which has to retrieve the schema from a MySql database (and will later be ported to other databases).
It is all working, except for COLUMN_DEFAULT - this seems to return an empty string for all nullable Text and VarChar items, whether the actual default is NULL or ''.

```
    CREATE TABLE `Schedule` (
      `idSchedule` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ActionDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `RepeatType` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `Task` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `Url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Parameters` text,
      `Post` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`idSchedule`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable cols = conn.GetSchema("Columns");
        foreach(DataRow c in cols.Select("TABLE_NAME = 'Schedule' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Url'")) {
            Console.WriteLine(c["COLUMN_DEFAULT"] == System.DBNull.Value ? "null" : "'" + c["COLUMN_DEFAULT"] + "'");
        }
    }
```

This outputs ''.

Note that the information_schema Columns table shows `NULL` in COLUMN_DEFAULT

If I then do

```
    ALTER TABLE `Schedule` CHANGE COLUMN `Url` `Url` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

it still outputs ''.

Note that the information_schema Columns table still shows `NULL` in COLUMN_DEFAULT

If I then do

```
    ALTER TABLE `Schedule` CHANGE COLUMN `Url` `Url` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT ''
```

it still outputs ''.

Now the information_schema Columns table shows blank in COLUMN_DEFAULT

I am using MySql server 5.1.73 on ClearOs, MySql.Data 6.9.5.0.

Comment: Did you try this: `IsNull( c[ "COLUMN_DEFAULT" ] ) ? "null" : c[ "COLUMN_DEFAULT" ]` ?

Comment: The name 'IsNull' does not exist in the current context

Comment: However, using c.IsNull("COLUMN_DEFAULT") gives the same result as before.